# mongodb can't connect to server on local network (Windows 10)

Tags: mongodb

When I do: `mongo 192.168.1.3/foo -u pg -p 12345`
I get:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.5
connecting to: mongodb://192.168.1.3:27017/foo?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-02-02T05:16:59.939+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.1.3:27017, connection attempt failed: NetworkTimeout: Error connecting to 192.168.1.3:27017 :: caused by :: Socket operation timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:328:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I've tried turning off the firewall in windows defender, that didn't help and now I'm out of ideas.
Can someone suggest how to connect?

Comment: How did you start your database deamon? Is it bound to your IP address or to the loopback interface? And what about windows firewall itself? A timeout points more to firewall problem than to a config issue

Comment: I didn't do anything special so it's however the installer does it by default.

Comment: The first thing I'd check is the interface that the server is bound to. I suppose you can start it manually on the command line. Launch options here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod.

Comment: Thanks but that sounds like a linux only solution. I'm looking for someone with windows 10 experience to weigh in.

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out:

- From Start menu run services.msc
- Find MongoDB Server and click properties
- Path to Executable for me says: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.exe" --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.cfg" --service
- Run notepad as admin and open mongod.cfg
- Change  bindIp to 0.0.0.0
- Save it and restart that service.